# How can I add content from a helper method (including buttons, textfields, actions) to a tab created in a stage?

Tags: java, javafx

```
public void employeeMenu()
{
    //ADD LOG OUT BUTTON SOMEWHERE
    //setting stage

        StackPane empMenuStage = new StackPane();
        VBox empBox = new VBox(new Label("Employee Menu"));
        empMenuStage.getChildren().add(empBox);
        Scene empScene = new Scene(empMenuStage, 500, 500);

        Stage empStage = new Stage();
        empStage.setScene(empScene);
        empStage.setTitle("Employee Menu");




       TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
       Tab bookingReport = new Tab("Booking Report");
       Tab checkOutGuest = new Tab("Check Out Guest");
       Tab createGuestAccount = new Tab("Create Guest Account");
       Tab editGuestInformation = new Tab("Edit Guest Info");
       Tab createNewEmpAccount = new Tab("Create new Employee   Account");
       Tab editEmployeeAccount = new Tab("Edit Employee Account");
       Tab editRoomStatus = new Tab("Edit Room Status");

       tabPane.getTabs().add(bookingReport); //mitchell
       tabPane.getTabs().add(checkOutGuest); //emma
       tabPane.getTabs().add(createGuestAccount); //joey
       tabPane.getTabs().add(editGuestInformation);
       tabPane.getTabs().add(createNewEmpAccount);
       tabPane.getTabs().add(editEmployeeAccount);
       tabPane.getTabs().add(editRoomStatus);



       VBox tabBox = new VBox(tabPane);
       Scene scene = new Scene(tabBox, 500, 500);

       empStage.setScene(scene);
       empStage.setTitle("Employee Menu");
       empStage.close();
       empStage.show();

}
public Tab displayEmpMenu(Stage empStage)
{
    //button for check out a value guest 
    //then enter name of value guest 
    //Enter room of value guest
    //Confirmation Message (pick Y or N)
        Tab test = new Tab("hi");
        Button valueGuest = new Button("Check out Value Guest");
        Button generalGuest = new Button("Check out General Guest");

        valueGuest.setOnAction(e -> checkOutVG());
        generalGuest.setOnAction(e -> checkOutGeneral());

        GridPane layout = new GridPane();
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10 ));
        layout.setVgap(8);
        GridPane.setConstraints(valueGuest, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(generalGuest,0, 1 );
        layout.getChildren().addAll(valueGuest, generalGuest);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 650, 200 );
        empStage.setScene(scene);
        empStage.setTitle("Check Out Guest");

        empStage.show();
       //button for check out a general guest
       //button for return to employee menu
       return test;
}
public void checkOutVG()
{
        TextField vgName = new TextField("Enter name of value guest");
        String vgN = vgName.getText();
        Label name = new Label("Value Guest Name");

       TextField vgRoom = new TextField("Enter room of value guest");
       Label roomNum = new Label("Value Guest Room");
       double room = Double.parseDouble(vgRoom.getText());
       int room1 = (int)room;

      freeThisRoom(room1);
      Label vgRoom1 = new Label("Value Guest Room");

      TextField vgconfirm = new TextField("Confirmation: "
            + vgN + " is checking out of "
            + room1 + "(Y/N)");
      vgconfirm.getText();
      String text = "";
      if (vgconfirm.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
      {
            text = "Done. " + vgN + "is checked out of "
                + room1;
      }
      else 
      {
           text = "You entered no. Please re-enter information.";

      }

}
public void checkOutGeneral()
{
     TextField name = new TextField("Enter name of general guest");
     Label ggname = new Label("General Guest Name");
     String name1 = name.getText();

     TextField room = new TextField("Enter room number of general guest");
     Label roomNum = new Label("General Guest Room");
     double ggNum = Double.parseDouble(room.getText());
     int ggRoom = (int)ggNum;
     freeThisRoom(ggRoom);
     TextField vgconfirm = new TextField("Confirmation: "
             + name + " is checking out of "
             + ggRoom + "(Y/N)");
     vgconfirm.getText();
     String text = "";
     if (vgconfirm.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
     {
          text = "Done. " + name + "is checked out of "
                + ggRoom;
     }
     else 
     {
         text = "You entered no. Please re-enter information.";

     }
}
```

I need help adding this content to the check out guest tab in the employee menu method. I'm new to javafx so if anyone could help me figure this out it would be greatly appreciated! I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or what I need to fix but I'm kind of lost. I've been scouring the web/textbooks for a solution but either I'm missing something big or I haven't come across the solution yet.

Comment: indent reduced, language tagged

Comment: @miken32 Did editing automatically add that comment?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes it did. Guess I'll keep that in mind when editing from the review queues! I don't usually leave notes.